# Custom report from quote

Tags: reporting

I created a custom report type with Quote, quote line item and I have custom object called Cost.

On my Cost object I have Quote Quote__c Master-Detail(Quote) field, and Quote Line Item Quote_Line_Item__c  Lookup(Quote Line Item)

When I make a report, obviously I see the Quote and Quote line item values in my report, but I don't see anything from my Cost object, all the values is -.

On my Cost layout i see Cost name Cost type and Quote name values. Something like this:

```
Cost name Cost Type Quote
test      test      4324-4324
```

Why I don't see anything from cost in my report?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue,

1. Go to `Object Manager >> Open that "Cost" custom object>>` - In that details page check you're enable the **Enable Reports** option for that object.
2. If yes, Please go to that `Setup >> Quick find >> Report types >> Your created report type` - In that page make sure its included that **Cost** object as well.
3. If it's included, Please check the Fields from that **Cost** object is
   added into that custom report type.

Thanks.